# How can I solve this error? "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I am working on creating a site where users can post whatever products they want to sell. It includes title, picture and description of the product. When I tried uploading the data to firebase storage, it did not work well and said "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined." 
Which part should I fix to solve this problem?

```
<template>
  <div class="productimageFile">
   <div>
       <label for="add-title">タイトル</label>
       <input type='text' class="add-product-title" v-model="title">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="add-picture">画像</label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="customFile">
          <input @change="photoFile" id="itemImage" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif, image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
            class="custom-file-input" required>
          <label id="add-item-image-label" class="custom-file-label" for="add-item-image">ファイルを選択</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <label for="add-description">説明</label>
       <textarea class="discription" v-model="productDescription">説明記入欄</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
       <button @click='itemCreate' type="submmit" value="送信"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'ItemCreate',
  data: function () {
    return {
      title: '',
      itemImage: '',
      productDescription: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    photoFile: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let files = e.target.files
      this.productimageFile = files[0]

      console.log(this.productimageFileductimage)
    },
    itemCreate: function () {
    // 商品タイトル
      const title = this.title
      const productDescription = this.productDescription
      const itemImage = this.itemImage
      const { files } = itemImage[0]

      if (files.length === 0) {
      // ファイルが選択されていないなら何もしない
        return
      }

      const file = files[0] // 表紙画像ファイル
      const filename = file.name // 画像ファイル名
      const itemImageLocation = `item-images/${filename}` // 画像ファイルのアップロード先

      // TODO: 書籍データを保存する
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(itemImageLocation)
        .put(file) // Storageへファイルアップロードを実行
        .then(() => {
        // Storageへのアップロードに成功したら、Realtime Databaseに書籍データを保存する
          const itemData = {
            title,
            itemImageLocation,
            productDescription,
            createdAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          }
          return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('items')
            .push(itemData)
        })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

I am new to here so if i am doing something wrong, please tell me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Files is a local variable, change it to a global variable!

Example:

```
<template>
  <div class="productimageFile">
   <div>
       <label for="add-title">タイトル</label>
       <input type='text' class="add-product-title" v-model="title">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="add-picture">画像</label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="customFile">
          <input @change="photoFile" id="itemImage" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif, image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
            class="custom-file-input" required>
          <label id="add-item-image-label" class="custom-file-label" for="add-item-image">ファイルを選択</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <label for="add-description">説明</label>
       <textarea class="discription" v-model="productDescription">説明記入欄</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
       <button @click='itemCreate' type="submmit" value="送信"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

var { files } = null

export default {
  name: 'ItemCreate',
  data: function () {
    return {
      title: '',
      itemImage: '',
      productDescription: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    photoFile: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let files2 = e.target.files
      this.productimageFile = files2[0]

      console.log(this.productimageFileductimage)
    },
    itemCreate: function () {
    // 商品タイトル
      const title = this.title
      const productDescription = this.productDescription
      const itemImage = this.itemImage
      { files } = itemImage[0]

      if (files.length === 0) {
      // ファイルが選択されていないなら何もしない
        return
      }

      const file = files[0] // 表紙画像ファイル
      const filename = file.name // 画像ファイル名
      const itemImageLocation = `item-images/${filename}` // 画像ファイルのアップロード先

      // TODO: 書籍データを保存する
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(itemImageLocation)
        .put(file) // Storageへファイルアップロードを実行
        .then(() => {
        // Storageへのアップロードに成功したら、Realtime Databaseに書籍データを保存する
          const itemData = {
            title,
            itemImageLocation,
            productDescription,
            createdAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          }
          return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('items')
            .push(itemData)
        })
    }
  }
```

Edit: You should also work on your naming conventions, there are two different variables named 'files', this might also be a cause of an error. Save your self an error by naming your objects after what they do or what they are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it but my editor screen showed a warning in the line of  "{ files } = itemImage[0]", saying  "unexpected token =."  What should I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take files from the input element in `itemCreate` method as you have already done that in `photoFile` handler.

I modified your code a little bit.

```
<template>
  <div class="productimageFile">
   <div>
       <label for="add-title">タイトル</label>
       <input type='text' class="add-product-title" v-model="title">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="add-picture">画像</label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="customFile">
          <input @change="photoFile" id="itemImage" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif, image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
            class="custom-file-input" required>
          <label id="add-item-image-label" class="custom-file-label" for="add-item-image">ファイルを選択</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <label for="add-description">説明</label>
       <textarea class="discription" v-model="productDescription">説明記入欄</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
       <button @click='itemCreate' type="submmit" value="送信"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'ItemCreate',
  data: function () {
    return {
      title: '',
      itemImage: '',
      productDescription: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    photoFile: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let files = e.target.files
      this.productimageFile = files[0]

      console.log(this.productimageFileductimage)
    },
    itemCreate: function () {
    // 商品タイトル
      const title = this.title
      const productDescription = this.productDescription
      const itemImage = this.productimageFile

      if (!itemImage) {
      // ファイルが選択されていないなら何もしない
        return
      }

      const filename = itemImage.name // 画像ファイル名
      const itemImageLocation = `item-images/${filename}` // 画像ファイルのアップロード先

      // TODO: 書籍データを保存する
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(itemImageLocation)
        .put(itemImage) // Storageへファイルアップロードを実行
        .then(() => {
        // Storageへのアップロードに成功したら、Realtime Databaseに書籍データを保存する
          const itemData = {
            title,
            itemImageLocation,
            productDescription,
            createdAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          }
          return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('items')
            .push(itemData)
        })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```